# How to Integrate Facebook Like Button Inside jQuery Image Gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, facebook-like, image-gallery

Is it possible to integrate into jQuery Image Gallery facebook like button that will when a user clicks on it show the current image on user news feeds?
If yes, please tell me how.
Thanks!
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This plugin](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) comes with Facebook like button and Tweet button for each image

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have two questions: 1) where in javascript I have to declare the path to navigation icons/themes? 2) is there any image gallery that integrates facebook comments too?

Comment: 1) There's a CSS included, you've to modify the paths there
2) Don't think so, sorry

Comment: found it! thanks! 
I am having problem with facebook and twitter icons. They are not displayed as in the demos, and the edges are not sharp as in the demos. Is that a known bug since all I did was just copied the files?

Comment: OK, so... modify this css rule: `div.pp_default .pp_social {
display: block;
clear: both;
margin-top: 7px;
}`
And this: `.pp_social .twitter {
float: left;
width: auto !important!;
margin: 0 !important;
}`
and: `.pp_social .facebook {
float: left;
margin-left: 0 !important;
width: 100px !important;
}`

Comment: thx, it worked :)
From what I can see in my fb news feeds - it only displays my site name as the result of the like action. is it possible to display the image user has liked on his news feeds?

Comment: It is possible, but you'll have to build up a Facebook App and learn FBML/OpenGraph ... OR move each image to a single page and set a `meta property="og:image"`... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#website

Comment: I've made a fb app, and I've already implemented FBML/OG. You can try it when you click LIKE button on home page.
The problem is - ow to embedd it in the gallery...

Comment: Uhm, i think you've to code an "app action" to do it, but i can't help you for this, sorry